# Messenger app for Android with stickers auto-suggested describing actions as text messages are sent

Tags: android, chat, accessibility

I would like to know whether any messenger applications on Android auto-suggest stickers that describe the messages that are sent, but, in terms of describing via still or animated pictures, the actions being sent (for example, if the user is at home and says I am going shopping a picture of the user moving away from an icon of the home towards an icon of the supermarket is displayed).

I think, such a messenger, could be interesting (perhaps, it could be useful to children who might be more familiar with pictures than language, as well, as to people coming to grips with new languages (if such pictures could be accurate)).

Current messengers only seem to have stickers for describing emotions and items, but not actions.